# Is it true that $\tan{\frac{\pi}{4k}} \geqslant \frac{1}{k}$ for $k\geqslant 1$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $\tan{\frac{\pi}{4k}} \geqslant \frac{1}{k}$ for $k\geqslant 1$? I think this is true, but how to prove it?

Comment: Why would this be true?  For small $x$, $\tan x \sim x$.  So for large $k$, $\tan\frac{\pi}{4 k} \sim \frac{\pi}{4 k} < \frac{1}{k}$.  In fact, you have equality for $k=1$, and for all larger $k$ you have $\tan(\pi/(4k)) < 1/k$.

Comment: Can you make this argument more rigorous? @mjqxxxx

Comment: And for all other $k$ as well, as far as I can see. Did you mean to write $<$? Edit: This comment was in response to another comment, which has now been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Study the function $f\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}x)}{x} \tag{$x\neq 0$}
$$
extended by continuity with $f(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}<1$. You have $f(1)=1$, so even without proving that this function is increasing, you can tell from its continuity that  $f(x) \geq 1$ **cannot** be true for all $k\geq 1$ (as otherwise, by continuity we would have $f(0) \geq 1$).

By studying the function (using the real analysis tools at your disposal), you can in fact prove that $f$ is increasing, and thus that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. In particular, $f(1/k)\leq 1$ for all $k\geq 1$ (and the inequality is strict for any $k>1$).

Comment: Note: if $f$ being defined as the ratio gives you a hard time in the second part, you can consider instead the difference, $g(x) = \tan\frac{\pi x}{4} - x$ instead (derivatives are a bit nicer; and we have $g(0)=g(1)=0$. Now, you would need to show that $g(x) < 0$ on $(0,1)$).